# How to specify "OR" in Text.Contains, C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, contains

If I use:

```
if (MainTextBox.Text.Contains("red" + "blue"))
```

Then textbox must contain both terms. But how can I specify textbox to contain either one or the other?

Comment: Note that your current code is equivalent to `MainTextBox.Text.Contains("redblue")` which is not quite the same as `MainTextBox.Text.Contains("red") && MainTextBox.Text.Contains("blue")`

Comment: Yes, thank you. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to check if the textbox contains either red `or` blue, you may write

```
if (MainTextBox.Text.Contains("red") || MainTextBox.Text.Contains("blue"))
```

Otherwise, if the textbox must contain both red `and` blue you may write

```
if (MainTextBox.Text.Contains("red") && MainTextBox.Text.Contains("blue"))
```

Comment: Is it `||` or `&&` what OP wants? OP mentions both in his question: "must contain both" ... "contain either one or the other"

Comment: Thank you, this has answered all my questions!

Answer (score 1):

You should check separately for `red` and `blue`

```
string text = MainTextBox.Text;
bool containsAny = text.Contains("red") || text.Contains("blue");
bool containsBoth = text.Contains("red") && text.Contains("blue");
```

Or you can use regex

```
bool containsAny = Regex.IsMatch(text, "(red|blue)");
bool containsBoth = Regex.IsMatch(text, "(?=.*red)(?=.*blue)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if (MainTextBox.Text.Contains("red") || MainTextBox.Text.Contains("blue"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `||`(or `&&`) you could also use `String.Contains` and LINQ:

```
string[] itemsToContain = { "red", "blue" };
if (itemsToContain.All(MainTextBox.Text.Contains))
{
    // here the TextBox contains both terms as a substring
}
if (itemsToContain.Any(MainTextBox.Text.Contains))
{
    // here the TextBox contains  one of both as a substring
}
```

Here's a version that ignores the case, so where it doesn't matter if it's `Red` or `red`:

```
if (itemsToContain.All(s => MainTextBox.Text.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))
{
    // here the TextBox contains both terms as a substring ignoring the case
}
```